# Is it possible to have DataSource injection with composite unit?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

With a conventional persistence unit, it is possible to inject a DataSouce via @Resource.
Now, I have a composite unit and i want to know if i can have access to a DataSouce of the composite unit?

Comment: Have you tried? From what I gather on composite _Persistence_ Units is that each can have their own `DataSource`. They would be exposed under different JNDI names and looked up as such via `@Resource`. That they form a composite unit is/should be on a conceptually separate level.

Comment: it seems that the problem is not the injection of datasource via @Resource declaration but my composite unit that does not work!
I made another post for this specific problem : [Why the datasource not found in a composite unit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23477112/why-the-datasource-not-found-in-a-composite-unit)